# Bouncing ball in processing

Tags: processing

Trying to make a simple bouncing ball program in processing, but having trouble removing the ghosting of the ball. Any help would be appreciated, here is the code I have:

```java
float g=-9.81;
float k=0.2;    // Spring constant
float m=0.25;   // Mass kg
float dt=0.01;  // Time step 50ms

float vy=0;     // Initial velocity
float y=0.95;   // Initial position

float t=0;      // Initial time

void setup()
{
size(500, 500);
 }

void draw()
{
 vy=vy+(g-((k/m)*vy))*dt; 
if(y<0)
{
vy=-vy;
} 

y=y+(vy*dt); 
t=t+dt;

float sx=map(0.5,0,1,0,width);
float sy=map(y,0,1,height-1,0);
fill(255,0,0);
ellipse(sx,sy,10,10);
}
```

Comment: Note that you don't need to remove the entire previous ball; just the bit that's no longer required. Otherwise your image will tend to flicker. I wrote something like that as a 12 year old boy on a Z80 chip in machine code, and was paid for it ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're never clearing out old frames, so anything you draw is simply drawn on top of whatever you drew before.

If you want to clear out the old frames, add a call to the `background()` function as the first line in your `draw()` function.

More info can be found in [the reference](https://processing.org/reference/background_.html) or in [this tutorial](http://happycoding.io/tutorials/processing/animation) on animation in Processing (disclaimer: I wrote that tutorial).